# How to install MT7612U Drivers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I want to install MT7612U Drivers for wifi connectivity on my Ubuntu 16.04 How can i install through terminal

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`